# Javascript function to play and pause video

Tags: javascript, html5-video

I am trying to start and pause an html5 video at certain points via a clickable play button that includes the start time and end time:

```
function videostart(id,start,end){

  var video = document.getElementsByTagName("video")[0];
  video.currentTime = start;
  video.play();

  video.addEventListener("timeupdate", function() {
  if (video.currentTime >= end) {
  video.pause();
  }}, false);

};
```

This first call works fine and it starts playing at 0 and ends at 2:24.

```
<a href="#" onclick="videostart('1759',0.00,2.24); return false;">PLAY</a>
```

However, this second call starts to play and then immediately stops:

```
<a href="#" onclick="videostart('1760',2.25,7.24); return false;">PLAY</a>
```

If I click the first link first, it works fine and plays from 0 to 2.24.

If I click the second link FIRST, it plays fine and stops fine as well.

However, if I click the first link FIRST and THEN click the second link, it starts to play and then quits immediately.

I can, at that point go back and play the first link as many times as I wish without issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [`.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) & [`.removeEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener)

First of all avoid using onevent attribute handlers:

> **<button <del>onclick="fnc()"</del>>**

You'll need to remove the `timeupdate` event handler because it'll continually update on whatever was the initial `end` value. That means `.addEventListener()` and `.removeEventListener()` is needed.

### Demo

**Details are commented in demo**

```js
/*
Register the document to the click event
When it's clicked, call function videoStart()
*/
document.addEventListener('click', videoStart);
// Declare variable
var END;
// Define function videoStart() -- pass Event Object
function videoStart(event) {
  // Reference the clicked button
  var button = event.target;
  // Get data-start value of clicked button
  var start = button.dataset.start;
  // Get data-end value of clicked button
  var end = button.dataset.end;
  // Assign value of end to END
  END = end;
  // Reference the video tag
  var video = document.querySelector("video");
  // Set time to start value
  video.currentTime = start;
  // Play video
  video.play();
  /* 
  Register video tag to timeupdate event 
  videoEnd() is the callback function
  */
  video.addEventListener("timeupdate", videoEnd);
};

// Define function videoEnd() -- pass the Event Object
function videoEnd(event) {
  // Reference the video tag
  var video = document.querySelector("video");
  /*
  if the current time is greater than or equal to END...
  pause video and remove the eventListener() so the next
  eventListener can be established according to new END
  argument.
  */
  if (video.currentTime >= END) {
    video.pause();
    video.removeEventListener("timeupdate", videoEnd);
  }
}
```

```html
<video src='https://html5demos.com/assets/dizzy.mp4' width='320'></video>
<button data-start='0' data-end='3'>0 - 3</button>

<button data-start='3' data-end='5'>3 - 5</button>
```

Comment: Great answer!  Thanks much @zer00ne!!

Comment: Thank you, sir. Happy coding!